# Extending Django User Model and Accessing it

Tags: python, django

I extended the User model in Django with a model called Client.

It looks like this:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Clients")
        verbose_name = _("Client")
        permissions = (
            ("can_upload", _("Can upload files.")),
            ("can_access_uploads", _("Can access upload dashboard.")),
            ("is_client", _("Is a client.")),
        )
```

However, I cannot figure out how to access this model through the current user in a view for example:

```
def dashboard(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_client = Client.objects.filter(user__icontains=current_user)

    files = ClientUpload.objects.filter(client__icontains=current_client)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = UploadFile(file = request.FILES['file'])
            new_file.save()

        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    data = {'form': form, 'client': current_client, 'files': files}
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

ClientUpload Model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ClientUpload(models.Model):

    client = models.OneToOneField(Client)

    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        url = "uploads/%s/%s" % (self.client.company, filename)
        return url

    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Client Uploads")
        verbose_name = _("Client Upload")
```

I get the current user with `request.user` but I can't figure out how to get the client related to that user.  When I load the dashboard view I get the error:

"Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains"

How can I access the client model associated with a user when I extend the user model in this fashion according to the docs?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Why would you think `icontains` would be the right thing to do? That's what you use when you want to case-insensitively match part of a CharField against a string, which has nothing at all to do with what you're doing.

Comment: There is no need for the `icontains` lookup, just use `Client.objects.filter(user=current_user)` and `ClientUpload.objects.filter(client=current_client)`

Comment: Thanks that seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `Client` object for a given `User` like this:

```
    client = request.user.client
```

Comment: No need for the related_name. It is already `client` by default.

Comment: I tried accessing it that way and got the error:RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no client.

Comment: Are you sure the User has a related client object?

Comment: It did work I was just logged in with the wrong account that didn't have Client associated\